# PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null,

Tags: php

I'm studying php and trying to integrate it with oop on my own,can anyone explain idea of this error ?

As I guess it can't find a query and but I can't get why,because in `$query` everything is correct, p.s global `$mysqli` is for test purposes only,I know using it carelessly is bad.

```
    <?php 

class Index{
    public function connect(){
    $mysqli=new mysqli();
    $mysqli->connect('localhost',"root","");
    $conn=$mysqli->select_db("webartisan");

    if($mysqli->errno){
    echo "Unable to connect to the database: ".$mysqli->error;
    exit();
    }
 }
public function select_data($table,$id){
    $query="SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE id=$id  ";
    }
    public function insert_data(){
        global $conn;
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $query="INSERT INTO artisan(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')";

        $result=$conn->query($query);

        if($result->num_rows){
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function register(){
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            self::insert_data();
        }
    }   
}
$index=new Index();
$index->register();
?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\webartisan\index.php:23 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webartisan\index.php(31): Index->insert_data() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webartisan\index.php(36): Index->register() #2 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\webartisan\index.php on line 23

Comment: If you want to share variables between methods of a class, then `$conn` should be `$this->conn` which means you can get rid of `global $conn`

Comment: but $conn is inside a function,so i should find other way of doing it?

Comment: Your functions are wrapped in class, they behave a bit differently to what you're expecting. Change `self::insert_data();` to become `$this->insert_data();` because there's no need for a static call. I'm not sure where you're calling `connect()` from either.

Comment: _i should find other way of doing it?_ @Scuzzy gave you the right direction... Get rid of `global` where ever you can.. code  OOP

Comment: now $conn is undefined,i called connect() but still undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$conn` variable is not accessible as global variable because you declare `$conn` as local variable inside `connect()` method.

To address this problem, you need to declare as class field and then you can access `$conn` as `$this->conn` inside any methods of class `Index`. This way you do not need `global $conn`.

For example:

```
<?php
class Index{
    private $conn;

    public function connect() {
        ...
        $this->conn = $mysqli->select_db("webartisan");
        ...
    }

    public function insert_data() {
        ...
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);
        ...
    }    
}
```

**Update:**

`select_db()` returns boolean value, not connection object. Following line will cause `Call to a member function query() on boolean` error as you said in comment.

```
$this->conn = $mysqli->select_db("webartisan");
```

You should read [mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: now it says that Call to a member function query() on boolean,that means it returns false for some reason right?

Comment: Correct, it means your connection failed.

Comment: @DummyTarget It is different issue.

Comment: could you tell me please what issue?

Comment: i did return $mysqli and it worked but is it the right way of doing it?